# Override detail page with rowsperlist parameter

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides

I'm trying to append the parameter "rowsperlist" to an object detail view. So, I've created a page to override the "view" button for that object with an action to redirect to the original record with the parameters "nooverride=1" and "rowsperlist=50". The redirect is done correctly but the parameter "rowsperlist" gets lots somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some code to illustrate how your attempting this at present and what things you've tried?

Comment: I've just created a page with the action like this:
"/{!Object__c.Id}?nooverride=1&rowsperlist=50". I've also tried to create a controller to return a PageReference with the same string but with no success...